# How to get value of a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my div:

```
<div id="demo" align="center"  value="1">
    <h3>By Color</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="color1" value="#990000"  onClick="changeColor()"/><label for="color1">Red</label>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="color2" value="#009900" onClick="changeColor()"/><label for="color2">Green</label>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="color3" value="#FFFF00" onClick="changeColor()" /><label for="color3">Yellow</label><br><br><br>
</div>
```

I want the value attribute of that div (value="1").

I am trying like this:

```
function overlay()
{
    var cookieValue = document.getElementById("demo").value;    
    alert(cookieValue);
}
```

but it is showing "Undefined" how to get value 1 using javascript please suggest any solution,.

Comment: "Value of a div" ?? May be there's a better way of doing what you want..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`DIV`s do not have a `value` *property*.

Technically, according to the DTDs, they shouldn't have a `value` *attribute* either, but generally you'll want to use `.getAttribute()` in this case:

```
function overlay()
{
    var cookieValue = document.getElementById('demo').getAttribute('value');
    alert(cookieValue);
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this might be troublesome with some version of IEs ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531508/getattribute-cannot-return-class-in-ie7

Comment: @DhruvPathak I won't argue over whether odd versions of IE might struggle with this--odd versions of IE seem to struggle with everything. The link you posted, however, is not related to the topic at hand. That link refers to IE's _proper_ referencing of the `class` attr as `className`. If you're the one who downvoted me, I really don't understand why.

Comment: Sorry yar i just want to give + but unfortunately i clicked on down arrow I want to change but it is not moving

Comment: @JAAulde your fiddle is broken

Comment: @Mahi Thanks, I've removed the link

Answer (score 27):

To put it short 'value' is not an valid attribute of div. 
So it's absolutely correct to return undefined.

What you could do was something in the line of using one of the HTML5 attributes 'data-*'

```
<div id="demo" align="center"  data-value="1">
```

And the script would be:

```
var val = document.getElementById('demo').getAttribute('data-value');
```

This should work in most modern browsers
Just remember to put your doctype as `<!DOCTYPE html>` to get it valid

Answer (score 5):

As I said in the comments, a `<div>` element does not have a `value` attribute. Although (very) bad, it can be accessed as:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('demo').getAttribute);
```

I suggest using HTML5 `data-*` attributes rather. Something like this:

```
<div id="demo" data-myValue="1">...</div>
```

in which case you could access it using:

```
element.getAttribute('data-myValue');
//Or using jQuery:
$('#demo').data('myValue');
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all

```
<div id="demo" align="center"  value="1"></div>
```

that is not **valid HTML**. Read up on custom data attributes or use the following instead:

```
<div id="demo" align="center" data-value="1"></div>
```

Since "data-value" is an attribute, you have to use the **getAttribute function** to retrieve its value.

```
var cookieValue = document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("data-value");
```

Comment: I'm sure you're well aware, but for the OPs sake I'll make it clear that `data-value` is only valid with an HTML 5 DOCTYPE. Without it, `data-value` and `value` are equally invalid. Furthermore, if one is running a customized DOCTYPE, `value` _could_ be a valid attribute. The latter comment is a stretch, I admit. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var theValue = document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Value is not a valid attribute of DIV

try this

```
var divElement = document.getElementById('demo');
alert( divElement .getAttribute('value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

div element:

```
<div tabindex="0" role="button" id="state_field">CA</div>
```

call `.innerHTML` to get value 'CA'

```
document.getElementById("state_field").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the value of the div, you can use **innerHTML**.

You can try this:

```
function overlay()
{
    var cookieValue = document.getElementById("color1").innerHTML;    
    alert(cookieValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add data-value custom attr to div element

```
  <div id="demo" align="center"  data-value="1">
<h3>By Color</h3>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="color1" value="#990000"  onClick="changeColor()"/><label for="color1">Red</label>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="color2" value="#009900" onClick="changeColor()"/><label for="color2">Green</label>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="color3" value="#FFFF00" onClick="changeColor()" /><label for="color3">Yellow</label><br><br><br>
```

then use this code for function which try get data-value

```
var cookieValue = document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute('data-value');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<!-- get text from a div -->

function get_invoice_details(){
    var get_prod_code = document.getElementById('product_code').textContent
    console.log('get_prod_code ::',get_prod_code)
}
get_invoice_details()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).