# Getting the value of multiple "contenteditables" in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this for loop which everytime creates a new div that's [contenteditable](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp):

```
for($i=0; $i<$something; $i++){
   echo '<div id='.$value[$i].' contenteditable></div>';
}
```

Now I want to get each div their own value out of it and use that. This shouldn't be that hard but I've never worked with this attribute and there is not a lot of information about this attribute. Also I'd like the value to show up whenever something is changed. So basically an onchanged event. These values will be used in a query. The thing is I cant seem to figure out how to work with this(also I dont have a lot of experience in javascript).

How would I get the value of these divs everytime they change and show them with their div id's?

Comment: do you have any js so far?

Comment: @atmd No. I cant seem to figure out how to proceed. There is enough information about getting the value in javascript like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238508/how-to-get-value-of-a-div-using-javascript , but I dont understand how I would use my id's in that answer. Also if anything changes with the conteditable?

Comment: i'd suggest initially giving the elements a common class, so you can listen for changes based on the class rather then try to get the `id`'s. You can always get the `id` in the event listener if you need it. [this answer might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events)

Comment: @atmd This still means the class= php values depending on the state of the loop. How would I use this in javascript?

Comment: the class would be hard coded, for example `echo '<div class="editable-area"  id='.$value[$i].' contenteditable></div>';` then you'd add your listener to the `.editable-area`  class rather then each `id`  see @verjas's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could to put a "class" to all your divs to get fast access to them:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$something; $i++){
   echo '<div id='.$value[$i].' class="editable" contenteditable></div>';
}
```

The you can use jQuery to get the "input" event on a div and retrieve the value and the id - example: http://jsfiddle.net/se2nj78L/

```
$(".editable").on("input",function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
        var html="<p>Content changed in div with id="+id+"</p>";
        html+=$(this).html();
       $("#feedback").html(html);
});
```

To use only JS,  it would be something like:

```
var editable_divs= document.getElementsByClassName("editable");

for (var i=0; i<editable_divs.length; i++) {
    editable_divs[i].addEventListener("input",
        function () { /* some function */}
        ,false);
}
```

For simple JS: http://jsfiddle.net/87vv4vg1/1/

EDIT:

To get all div contents that were changed, you can change the function to something like here: http://jsfiddle.net/7me8okgd/

Basically you put all the changes in a big object, where for each id you have the changed content of the div - example:

```
var div_changes = {};
/* var div_changes = {
     1: "Content from div with id='1'",
     2: "Content from did with id='2'",
     ...
 } 
 */

for (var i=0; i<editable_divs.length; i++) {
    editable_divs[i].addEventListener("input",
        function () { 
            div_changes[this.id]=this.innerHTML;
        }
        ,false);
}
```

You can use this object for multiple purposes afterwards (like send it through AJAX).

Comment: This is almost it, but in your jsfiddle it only shows the result of the last editted one though.

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure what was the final result you wanted. You can update the function anyway you want. Do you want to store all the div contents in a variable to send by AJAX?

Comment: Just show all the variables updated whenever it's changed on screen. So like it is now but show all instead of the last changed.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an option. Just add a `keyup` listener to all editable elements and then collect the `innerHTML` of each element. To get the current editable elements `id` just use `this` in the `keyup` handler.

Sure you will get the idea.

```js
var editableElems = document.querySelectorAll('.edit'),
    output = document.getElementById('output'),
    crntId = document.getElementById('current-id');

function collectData() {
  var editableElemsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(editableElems);
  output.innerHTML = "";
  editableElemsArray.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
    output.innerHTML += value.innerHTML;
  });
}

function editKeyUpHndl() {
  crntId.innerHTML = this.getAttribute('id');
  collectData();
}

for(var i = 0;  i < editableElems.length; i++) {
  editableElems[i].addEventListener('keyup', editKeyUpHndl, false);
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.edit {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #fff, inset 0 -1px 2px #111;
  color: #888;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 85%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

#output {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 4px;    
}

#current-id {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  background: #ddd;
  height: 34px;
  min-width: 120px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="edit" id="edit-box-01" contenteditable>
  <p>Edit One</p>
</div>

<div class="edit" id="edit-box-02" contenteditable>
  <p>Edit Two</p>
</div>

<div class="edit" id="edit-box-03" contenteditable>
  <p>Edit Three</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="current-id"> </div>
  <div id="output"></div>    
</div>
```