# How can I read a text from a php site with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

my php site will echo a number. Now I want to read the content with JavaScript. How can i do this.

Comment: *"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238508/how-to-get-value-of-a-div-using-javascript

Comment: `$.get('phpscript.php', function(data) { alert('The number is: ' + data); });`

Comment: inside js script 

`var myContent = "'"+<?php echo number; >+"'";`

Comment: My PHP script is not on the same document as the javascript.

Comment: Check my answer, it contains both a jQuery and a non-jQuery answer.

Comment: @NilsBergmann: We would need to know the structure of what you're trying to do.  In a broad sense, your JavaScript can make an AJAX request to the PHP page and read the response of that request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following with jQuery:

```
$.get("http://www.myawesomephppage.com/page.php", function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Or without jQuery:

```
var con = new XMLHttpRequest();
con.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (con.readyState == 4 && con.status == 200) {
        alert(con.responseText);
    }
};
con.open("GET", "http://www.myawesomephp.com/mypage.php", true);
con.send();
```