# I am not able to send value attribute to server with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(function(){

$('.menu').on('click', (function(){
    $('#box').toggle('slide');
     $.ajax({
         url:'fetchsubmenu.php';
         data : {nume : $(this).attr('value')},
         dataType : 'json'
    });
});
$('.menu').on('mouseout',function(){
        $('#box').hide();
    });
});
```

I am trying to send some elements values to server in order to select some data from database but it doesn't work. With code like this, the box doesn't toggle any more. Is there a better way to do this?

```
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('alinDataBase');

$nume = $_GET['nume'];

$query =  "SELECT (nume) FROM submenu WHERE categorie = '$nume' ";
$result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
$output='';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $output=array(
    "nume" => $row["nume"],
    );
    $records[] = $output;
}
echo json_encode($records);

mysql_close($conn);
```

and the html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="foodstore.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fetchSubmenu.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>
    <body id="body">
            <div id = "aseazamenu">

     <div class ="menu" value = "audio" >Audio,Video </div><br>
     <div class ="menu" value = "electro" >Electrocasnice</div><br>
     <div class ="menu" value = "ingrijire" >Ingrijire   personala</div><br>
     <div class ="menu" value = "pc" >PC</div><br>
     <div class ="menu" value = "telefoane" >Tablete,Telefoane</div><br>

 </div>
            <div >
                    <table id="box">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

update :
to display my results I used this:

```
      function showObjects(obiecte){

    $('#box tbody').html('');
        for(var i=0; i<obiecte.length; i++){               
            var aparat = obiecte[i];
            $('#box tbody').append(getRow(aparat));
        }
}

function getRow(aparat){

    var row = '<tr>'+
        '<td>' + '<a href=produs.html>'+aparat.nume+'</a>' + '</td>'+               
        '</tr>';

        return row;
}

$.ajax({
    url:"fetchSubmenu.php",
    dataType:'json',
    catche:false
}).done(function(result){
    console.debug('3) ajax done', result);
    showObjects(result);
});
```

Comment: FYI.. Value is not a `attribute` for `div` element. Instead `value` try using `data-value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a sucess function so you can process the response from the server

html:

```
<div id="aseazamenu">
    <div class="menu" data-value="audio">Audio,Video</div><br>
    <div class="menu" data-value="electro">Electrocasnice</div><br>
    <div class="menu" data-value="ingrijire">Ingrijire personala</div><br>
    <div class="menu" data-value="pc">PC</div><br>
    <div class="menu" data-value="telefoane">Tablete,Telefoane</div><br>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.menu').on('click', (function(){
    $('#box').toggle('slide');
     $.ajax({
         url:'fetchsubmenu.php';
         data : {nume : $(this).attr('data-value')},
         dataType : 'json',
         success:function(data){
         console.log(data);// process your response 
         var rows = '';
         $.each(data,function(i,v){
              rows+= '<tr><td><a href=produs.html>'+v.nume+'</a></td</tr>';
         });
         $('#box tbody').html(rows);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I updated my question , in console i get: [Object, Object] but on the "box" div nothing

Comment: my fellow romanian can you provide the response body so i can show you how to build the dom elements?

Comment: i have updated my answer based on the information provided in the question, this should display the names in your table

Comment: I don't think displaying the result is the problem because when I replace $nume = $_GET['nume'] with $nume = 'audio' (exemple of value I am expecting) it works, the submenu names are displayed

Comment: done, updated my code with your last edit and it works like a charm! Thank you fellow romanian

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML,

```
<div id="aseazamenu">
    <div class="menu" data-value="audio">Audio,Video</div><br>
    <div class="menu" data-value="electro">Electrocasnice</div><br>
    <div class="menu" data-value="ingrijire">Ingrijire personala</div><br>
    <div class="menu" data-value="pc">PC</div><br>
    <div class="menu" data-value="telefoane">Tablete,Telefoane</div><br>
</div>
```

Reference,

https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

And in JS, make change,

```
data: {
    nume : $(this).attr('data-value')
},
```

Comment: Or you can use `data : {nume : $(this).data('value')},`

Comment: `$(this).data('value')` is the right way of using data-value. But thats not the problem in this question. `$(this).attr('value')` also works, you can't say that it won't work, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the attribute, you have an extra bracket. value will work just fine, you don't need data-value like others are saying.

Just change this:

```
$('.menu').on('click', (function(){
```

to this:

```
$('.menu').on('click', function(){
```

also in your ajax request, replace `;` by `,` after url.

Your code should look like this:

```
$('.menu').on('click', function(){
    $('#box').slideToggle();
     $.ajax({
         url:'fetchsubmenu.php',
         data : {nume : $(this).attr('value')},
         type : 'GET',
         dataType : 'json',
         success:function(data){
         console.log(data);
        },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Beautiful Answer, check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238508/how-to-get-value-of-a-div-using-javascript

Comment: alin, use `$('#box').slideToggle();` , don't forget to accept my answer if does the trick

Comment: @user1735921 now it toggles but my server still gets no data

Comment: Have you corrected the url value, like I said, see my edited, answer, you have to put comma instead of semicolon.

Comment: Yes I did  $.ajax({
    url:'fetchsubmenu.php',
       data:{nume : $(this).attr('value')},
    dataType : 'json'
        });