# Getting the value of a div tag's special attribute

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

If next command:

```
 console.log(document.getElementById('container'));
```

prints:

```
 <div id="container" prjid="ABCDE">...</div>
```

why the next command:

```
 console.log(document.getElementById('container').prjid);
```

prints undefined? I am trying to get the value of prjid

Comment: You shouldn't use nonstandard attributes. If you need to add your own data to an element, use `data-prjid`.

Comment: @ Jose Cabreta Zuniga, did it work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value of a div using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238508/how-to-get-value-of-a-div-using-javascript)

Comment: all is working now. Why I should not use nonstandard attributes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`prjid` is an attribute. You should use the function [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to get any attributes value.

> getAttribute() returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be null or "" (the empty string);

---

```js
 console.log(document.getElementById('container').getAttribute("prjid"));
```

```html
 <div id="container" prjid="ABCDE">...</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to get `prjid` which isn't a defined attribute on div rather a custom one, you would use [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```
document.getElementById('container').getAttribute('prjid')
```

Snippet

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('container').getAttribute('prjid'));
```

```html
<div id="container" prjid="abd"/>
```

According the MDN docs:

> getAttribute() returns the value of a specified attribute on the
>   element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned
>   will either be null or "" (the empty string);

Note:  In React you shouldn't use document.getElementById and rather use refs. Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele/38093981#38093981)** answer

Answer (score 2):

In order to get prjid use `getAttribute`

```
document.getElementById('container').getAttribute('prjid');
```

`getAttribute()` returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be null or "" (the empty string);

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this you can get data attribute to that
like below

```
document.getElementsById("container").getAttribute("prjid");
```

Comment: *set data attribute to that* ? you mean *get* ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by `getAttribute` function like

```
console.log(document.getElementById('container').getAttribute("prjid"));
```

You can read about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp)

Answer (score 1):

if you want get an value , and that value place in an custom attribute you must use getAttribute() method , some thing like this

```
var pjid = document.getElementById('container').getAttribute('pjid');
```

and create this attribute in your element

```
<div id="container" pjid="some-thing" >
```

but i thing you are this problem in React , because you Tag reactjs , in react ( prev version - less than 16 ) , JSX delete all undefined attribute but this problem solve in react 16 , you must migrate to this version