# Dynamically called function, argument not defined

Tags: javascript, function, dynamically-generated

I am dynamically generating a gallery, each gallery item has an onClick event that calls a function which has the items value as argument.

I tested the code without the " " and the value is defined but the function runs when the item is created and not when clicked.

When I use the " " the function only runs when I click it but I get *value not defined*

I would like to dynamically create the function, and trigger it on click using the value as argument.

jsGallery is an array that I'm cycling to build the gallery items.

Gallery Item code

```
function createDiv(type) {
  jsGallery.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.type === type) {
      let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.setAttribute("value", item.id);
      newDiv.setAttribute("class", "item" + " " + type);
      newDiv.setAttribute("id", "dynamic");

      newDiv.setAttribute("onClick", "testFire(value)");

      document.getElementById("galleryContainer").appendChild(newDiv);
    }
  })
}
```

TestFire function

```
function testFire(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: The value attribute does not exist for div elements. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238508/how-to-get-value-of-a-div-using-javascript/11238555

Comment: Where did you expect `value` to be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `testFire` (`value`) is a non-existing binding, that's why it returns undefined.

Instead of

`newDiv.setAttribute("onClick", "testFire(value)");`,

do:

`newDiv.onclick = () => testFire(newDiv.value);`

Btw, it still returned `undefined` because div-elements only have [global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andre Neuchter, I used your method but changed it sligthly as value was still returning as not defined.

```
newDiv.onclick = () => testFire(item.id);
```