# Why document.getElementById() command doesn't work on my code?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn innerHTML commands, but it's just showing me "Author: " text.

HTML side

```
  <h1 id="author">Author: </h1>
  <p>Sabir Türkleri'nin ve Batı Göktürk boylarının devamı olan Hazarlar, Göktürk birliği döneminde Göktürklerin Batı kanadını oluşturmaktaydı.</p>
  </body>
```

JS side

```
   var content= "Ensar Ergok";
   document.getElementById("author").value=content;
```

Comment: You haven't said whether you're getting an error, but as you said in the question, it's `innerHTML`, not `value`, for an `h1` element, see the [linked question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238508/how-to-get-value-of-a-div-using-javascript). If you did get an error message, it'll be because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

Comment: *(There has to be a better dupetarget for the `value`/`innerHTML` thing though.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `innerText`, `textContent` or `innerHTML` instead of `value`.